# No Bluetooth adapter with Intel Centrino Wireless N-2230 and Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, drivers, bluetooth, iwlwifi, centrino

The Intel Centrino N-2230 is a WiFi+Bluetooth adapter. In my Notebook + Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installation, WiFi works fine.
However, I cannot switch on the Bluetooth device.

First attempt via GUI: System setting -> Bluetooth: The on-switch is disabled and the panel says "Bluetooth not found. Connect an adapter to use Bluetooth".

Downloaded the current *iwlwifi* firmware from the Intel site and placed it into /lib/firmware. But this didn't solve the problem.

Does the Bluetooth part need another piece of firmware? And does anybody know, where to get it from? Or can this issue be solved with just some configuration?

```
#rfkill list
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

#dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
[ 3889.279452] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[ 3889.279482] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[ 3889.279488] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[ 3889.279491] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[ 3889.279497] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized

#sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       Beschreibung: Kabellose Verbindung
       Produkt: Centrino Wireless-N 2230
       Hersteller: Intel Corporation
       Physische ID: 0
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:03:00.0
       Logischer Name: wlp3s0
       Version: c4
       Seriennummer: 68:5d:43:05:68:79
       Breite: 64 bits
       Takt: 33MHz
       Fähigkeiten: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       Konfiguration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.3.0-46-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 ip=192.168.175.32 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       Ressourcen: irq:33 memory:f7e00000-f7e01fff
  *-network
       Beschreibung: Ethernet interface
       Produkt: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       Hersteller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       ...

#lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b2bb Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0bda:0138 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5138 Card Reader Controller
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Is it a laptpop pr a desktop? Please add output of `lsusb` to your question.

Comment: It's a notebook, yes. And I added lsusb output.

Comment: Why do you think this laptop has BT? It is an option. I don't see any BT devices.

Comment: The laptop had a Windows7 life before and under Windows, Bluetooth worked well. Further, googling for the Intel Centrino N-2230 brings up this product specification:
https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/66889/intel-centrino-wireless-n-2230-single-band.html
which clearly states, that it has Bluetooth. Also, see the linked product brief.
So, yes, it definitly has built-in Bluetooth.